# How to rotate a point cloud so that the obb of the point cloud coincides with the abb

Tags: python, point-clouds, lidar, open3d

I have a series of radar point clouds and I have used shapfile to segment out several of these areas, which are all rectangular in shape from the z-axis. I would like to know if there is a way to rotate them so that one edge is parallel to the x or y axis. My idea is to create obb enclosing boxes with abb enclosing boxes and then compare the two and rotate them cyclically. Thanks!

```
aabb = cloud.get_axis_aligned_bounding_box()
aabb.color = (1, 0, 0)

obb = cloud.get_oriented_bounding_box()
obb.color = (0, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call [cloud.rotate()](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.PointCloud.html#open3d.geometry.PointCloud.rotate) directly to which you pass a 3x3 rotation matrix.

To get that 3x3 rotation matrix you have multiple options:

- axis-angle: [`open3d.geometry.get_rotation_matrix_from_axis_angle`](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.get_rotation_matrix_from_axis_angle.html)
- quaternion: [`open3d.geometry.get_rotation_matrix_from_quaternion`](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.get_rotation_matrix_from_quaternion.html)
- euler : [`open3d.geometry.get_rotation_matrix_from_xyz`](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.get_rotation_matrix_from_xyz.html) (and variants (`from_xzy, from_yxz, from_yzx, from_zxy, from_zyx`))
  (angles are in radians, not degrees)

e.g.

```py
cloud.rotate(o3d.geometry.get_rotation_matrix_from_axis_angle([np.radians(90), 0, 0]))
```

(this should apply a 90 degrees rotation on the x axis: adjust as needed)